# Google ad dependencies causes problems with the manifest

Tags: android

I am trying to get admob to work. So I added the following line in the dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
```

As a result it is giving me an error

```
Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'configchanges' in package 'android'
```

Also, it is generating an activity tag outside of the application tag. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is not related with admob, but it seems that you have a typo in your manifest. There is no attribute `configchanges` but there is `android:configChanges` look for that attribute of any `<activity>` tags in your manifest.

Regarding your comment try this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|s‌​creenLayout|uiMode|s‌​creenSize|smallestSc‌​reenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Comment: Yah there is no configchanges attributes but I didn't put configchanges. I put android:configchanges. Here is what I put  <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configchanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

Comment: Check my update there is just one letter changed the big C of *Changes*.

Comment: Actually it is changes to the big C but for some reason the tag above keep getting generated outside the application tag with little c

Comment: Are you sure that you edit the right file? The manifest should be in `<project root>/<module name>/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Yah I am absolutely positive that I am editing the right file. I even double checked with expanding my whole project directory

Comment: Oh ok, I got it working now. It turns out it generates the activity tag with little c for some reason. If you change that to big C it works and it won't generate any tag outside the application tag.